# I want write a code in swift UnsafeMutableRawPointer offset

Tags: ios, swift

Objective-C code works fine. I don't know how to migrate pointers to Swift.

The code Objective-C to Swift Error in * to UnsafeMutableRawPointer
The code is RGBArray to image.

```
//
- (UIImage *)imageWithGrayArray:(NSArray *)array {
    const int width  = 512;
    const int height = 512;

    NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
    NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;

    UInt32 * pixels = (UInt32 *)malloc(height * width * sizeof(UInt32));
    memset(pixels, 0, height * width * sizeof(UInt32));
    for (int i = 0;  i < array.count;i++ ) {
        NSArray *subArray = array[i];
        for ( int j = 0 ; j < subArray.count; j++) {

          *(pixels +i *width + j) = RGBAMake([subArray[j] intValue],[subArray[j] intValue], [subArray[j] intValue], 255);
        }
    }

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixels,
                                                 width, height,
                                                 bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                                 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
     UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context)];
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    free(pixels);
    return image;
}
```

Swift

```
let width = 512
let height = 512
let  bytesPerPixel = 4
let bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * 512
let bitsPerComponent  = 8

var pixels:UnsafeMutableRawPointer = malloc(width*height * MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: UInt32()))

memset(pixels, 0,width * height * MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: UInt32()) )
for i in 0 ..<  orArr.count {
    for j in 0 ..<  orArr[i].count {
        let offset = pixels + i * width + j

pixels.advanced(by: i * width + j).storeBytes(of: RGBMake(r: orArr[i][j] as! Int, g: orArr[i][j]  as! Int, b: orArr[i][j] as! Int, a: 255), as: Int.self)


        }

}
let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

let bufferPointer = UnsafeRawBufferPointer(start: pixels, count: 512*512)
for (index, byte) in bufferPointer.enumerated() {
    print("byte \(index): \(byte)")
}

let content:CGContext = CGContext(data: pixels, width: Int(width), height: Int(height), bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.last.rawValue|CGImageByteOrderInfo.order32Big.rawValue)!
let outPutImage:CGImage = content.makeImage()!

return UIImage(cgImage: outPutImage)
```

This Objective-C code in Swift error

```
*(pixels +i *width + j) = RGBAMake([subArray[j] intValue],[subArray[j] intValue], [subArray[j] intValue], 255);
```

**
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gow5a.png)

this is the error i  change  the code

1. I can push the code  in link  [The Code](https://pan.baidu.com/s/1jLa_JnBZQtKTmboqoOoB3g**)

Answer (score 2):

I would rewrite your code as follows:

```
func image(withGray array: NSArray) -> UIImage {
    let width = 512
    let height = 512

    let bytesPerPixel = 4
    let bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width
    let bitsPerComponent = 8

    let pixels = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>.allocate(capacity: height * width)
    pixels.initialize(repeating: 0, count: height * width)
    for i in 0..<array.count {
        let subArray = array[i] as! NSArray
        for j in 0..<subArray.count {

            pixels[i*width+j] = RGBAMake(subArray[j] as! Int, subArray[j] as! Int, subArray[j] as! Int, 255)
        }
    }

    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let context = CGContext(data: pixels,
        width: width, height: height,
        bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace,
        bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.last.rawValue|CGImageByteOrderInfo.order32Big.rawValue)!
    let image = UIImage(cgImage: context.makeImage()!)

    pixels.deinitialize(count: width * height)
    pixels.deallocate()
    return image
}
```

You are not showing how you declared `orArr` in your Swift code, so I use `array` of type `NSArray` as in your Objecive-C code.

(Generally, it is always preferable to use Swift Arrays rather than `NSArray`.)

The declaration of `RGBAMake` is also unclear, but I think I can assume it as taking 4 `Int`s and returns a `UInt32`.

You might need to modify my code to fit with your actual Swift code.

---

And some other points:

- `APrimitiveType *` in Objective-C should be converted to typed pointer in Swift, `UnsafePointer<APrimitiveType>` or `UnsafeMutablePointer<APrimitiveType>`. With typed pointers, some operations like `+` are defined with C-pointer rules.
- Generally, `(APrimitiveType *)malloc(numOfElements * sizeof(APrimitiveType))` can be converted to `UnsafeMutablePointer<APrimitiveType>.allocate(capacity: numOfElements)`.
- `*(aPointer + anInt)` is equivalent to `aPointer[anInt]` in C, and the latter syntax works in Swift with the same syntax and the same semantics.

Comment: i do it  but errro in `   let content:CGContext = CGContext(data: pixels, width: Int(width), height: Int(height), bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.first.rawValue|CGImageByteOrderInfo.order32Big.rawValue)!`    ` [Unknown process name] CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported parameter combination: set CGBITMAP_CONTEXT_LOG_ERRORS environmental variable to see the details
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: [the code error again](https://pan.baidu.com/s/1jLa_JnBZQtKTmboqoOoB3g)

Comment: @user9865359, You know you can edit your own question. Please edit your question and include your code as text. The line you have shown in the comment is not sufficient. Our security rule does not allow us to download something on web. Please include all function definitions including function header, and the code showing how you are calling the function.